# Retrieve child key one by one and display in label swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the child in Firebase and print them EACH in a label but when I'm retrieving the key its printing all at the same time. I'm still learning on the go so here's what i tried:

```
func retrieve(){

        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        let intakeRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userId!).child("Intake")

        intakeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let intake = snapshot.value{

                self.ref.child("Attendance").child("Checkin").child(intake as! String).child(userId!).child("BM050-3-3-IMNPD").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    for child in snapshot.children{
                        let key = (child as AnyObject).key as String
                        print(key)
                        label.text = key

                    }

                })

            }
        }) { (Error) in
            print("unable to retrieve name from nameRef")
        }

    }
```

The code I tried like i said is printing all at the same time. But i would like to print each one in a separate label. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: You're only changing the text of label.text, and you're changing it each time the loop runs the 'for child in snapshot'

Comment: Actually the data i want are dates. How do i print seperate dates in seperate labels? Like i want to save the first data into the first label, second data into the second label

Comment: Are the number of values being returned by the "observeSingleEvent" that you'll want to assign to a label going to vary or stay the same?

Comment: The ones that are already there will stay the same because they are previous dates new dates will be added as new child.

Comment: So sometimes it will have three children and you'll need to create three labels, and sometimes it will retrieve some other number of children and you'll need to create that many labels?

Comment: There won't be many, its only for showing purposes, maybe one or two more, or i could display them in a table view or something?

Comment: A table view would be easiest if the amount if data you'd like to display is subject to change. I can show you how you might do that.

Comment: If you could that be really great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll of course need to create a tableViewController and link it up to a TableView and assign your cell its own identifier, but this is a good outline of what you'd need to do in your own tableViewController:

```
class tableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var dataArray = [String]()
    var ref = Database.database().reference() //You didn't include your delcaration of ref in your code, so don't use this, just use the one you were already using.

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        retrieve()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        let data = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = data

        return cell
    }




    func retrieve(){

       let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        let intakeRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userId!).child("Intake")

        intakeRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let intake = snapshot.value{

                self.ref.child("Attendance").child("Checkin").child(intake as! String).child(userId!).child("BM050-3-3-IMNPD").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    for child in snapshot.children{
                        let key = (child as AnyObject).key as String
                       self.dataArray.append(key)

                    }

                })
               self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }) { (Error) in
            print("unable to retrieve name from nameRef")
        }

    }


}
```

Again you'll need to create your own `UItableView`, link it up to a `UITableViewController`, assign your own cell reuse identifier and make sure that cellForRowAt has the correct reuse identifier in it, and you'll need to change the `ref` variable in my provided code to the `ref` that you need to use.

Comment: I'll give that a try right now. Thank you! Will update if it works

Comment: I managed to do with some code tweaking from your one! Thank you so much!!